# Loss of power / warning lights amber

Tags: automatic-transmission, vauxhall

I drive a Vauxhall Antara 2009 automatic. This morning I had just left home when I felt as if the car had lost power . When I looked at the dash four lights were on. Engine/transmission management , DCS , ESP and ESP off . Switched engine on and off and the lights went off but it happened again this time no power on acceleration and same four lights. I waited a few minutes then car was running fine. Any ideas what’s going on?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: The loss of power could easily be "limp home" mode rather than anything actually mechanically wrong - the multiple simultaneous lights and the self-clearing leads me to think this is likely to be electrical in nature.

Comment: I took it to the garage today and yes it is electrical and low voltage getting to the accelerator which means I need to replace the pedal